DP for a variation of the knapsack problem?
I have a variation of the knapsack problem where each item has a profit ($p_i$), weight ($w_i$), and penalty ($t_i$). The objective is to maximize the summation of the selected items' profits minus the largest penalty of all selected items, $\text{MAX} \Big(\sum_i p_i x_i - \max (t_i x_i) \Big)$. I have developed a dynamic programming (DP) approach as follows:
Let dp_profit[i][j] represent the maximum total profit we can obtain by considering the first $i$ items with a total capacity $j$, and dp_penalty[i][j] represent the maximum penalty.
I initialized all DP tables with zeros. Then, I iterated through all items (beginning with $i = 1$) and capacities:

If item $i$ is not included, update dp_[i][j] as dp_[i - 1][j].
If item $i$ is included (i.e., $w_i \leq j$), update dp_[i][j] by considering the added profit and new maximum penalty factor based on:

newProfit = dp[i - 1][j - w_i] + p_i;
newPenalty = max(dp_penalty[i - 1][j - w_i], t_i);
if (newProfit > dp_profit[i][j] && newProfit - newPenalty >= dp_profit[i][j] - dp_penalty[i][j]) {
    dp_profit[i][j] = newProfit;
    dp_penalty[i][j] = newPenalty;
}

Finally, after iterating over all items and capacities:
maxProfit = dp_profit[n][C];
maxPenalty = dp_penalty[n][C];
objval = maxProfit - maxPenalty;

The issue is that the algorithm does not select any item if its penalty is larger than its profit, even though the item could be selected with others such that the total profit exceeds the maximum individual penalty. I attempted to address this by sorting the items in non-decreasing order based on the values of profit minus penalty for each item, so that items with positive profit-penalty values are selected first. However, if no individual item has a positive profit-penalty value, the algorithm fails to select any items.

Before trying to write code, I recommend writing out the value function and its recurrence relation.

@RobPratt I have written the value function and its recurrence relations in a code form to facilitate readying. I may be wrong.

Hint: the state also needs to include the current maximum penalty.

@RobPratt That's why I created two dp tables one for storing the maximum profit and the second to store the maximum penalty. Am I right?

Try one table with state $(i,j,m)$, where $m$ is the maximum penalty.
